# IE9 not clearing cache in between posts

Tags: internet-explorer, session, post, http-headers, browser-cache

I have a page that does the following:

1. Click button to submit form
2. Page posts to itself, and an SQL query is executed to update a field in the DB.
3. The code then checks if there were any affected rows from the query execution and it is echoed. I expect it to echo Affected rows "1"

In Firefox, Safari, and Chrome, this operation works every time without fail.
In IE9 though, it works the first time, maybe 2 times or even 3, and then it does something weird - **It echoes Affected rows "0"** - **even though the query executed just fine (the DB was updated).**

I believe this is a **cache problem** of some sort, because when i clear the browser cache in IE before step 1 (submitting the form) it works every time as desired.

Ive tried using this code:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

And this in the `<head>` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT" />
```

What is going on? How can i stop IE from playing up like this?

**Update:**

There seems to be some sort of inconsistency with PHP PDO's rowCount() (used to get affected rows)... In my case, i can't imagine how, but the inconsistency is linked to browser cache. Instead of using rowCount() after executing my query, i perform a SELECT to determine whether the field was updated with the new val. This seems to be working consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using PDO's rowCount() after executing the query, perform a SELECT query to determine whether the field was updated with the new val.

Pseudo code/SQL:

1. Update table set field = 'new value' where field = 'old value'
2. Select row from table where field = 'new value'
3. If row returned then the field was updated